# How to match two sets of data using MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have multiple MySQL tables with numerous rows that need to be returned in a table using PHP. The issue I am having is how to display the information correctly when one of the tables has numerous matching ID's.

Take this as an example. This is a table that would hold a schedule that the user(userID) has booked.

**bk_schedule**

```
id  userID  date    block   tos status
113 46  2013-12-31  3        yes    1
114 44  2013-12-26  1        yes    3
115 45  2013-12-31  1        yes    3
116 44  2013-12-31  2        yes    3
117 44  2013-12-31  1        yes    3
```

While it's saving this data it is also saving data into another table with what the user has selected as their "service" separated into new rows `foreach` service they selected.

**bk_service**

```
id  userID  bk_id   services
212 46       113    7
213 44       114    62
214 45       115    61
215 44       116    14
216 44       117    1
217 44       117    8
218 44       117    22
219 44       117    15
```

The bk_id is related to the bk_schedule id to form their relationship.

Now when I have to pull this information into a table using Laravel 4 I am getting all the results combined into each row if I use to different table variables. If I attempt to use that same table set using `JOIN's` I get the rows fine but they are looping through each service rather than combining (I guess since it's looping every row found counting it as a new row).

Kind of like this.

```
userID  bk_id   services
44       116    14
44       114    62
44       117    8
44       117    22
44       117    15
```

Here is the code that reflects that.

```
    public function showHistory($id) {

   $appointment = DB::table('bk_schedule')
    ->select('bk_schedule.id', 'bk_schedule.date', 'bk_timeslot.block', 'bk_status.status', 'pr_service.service')
    ->where('bk_schedule.userID', $id)      
    ->join('bk_status', 'bk_schedule.status', '=', 'bk_status.id')
    ->join('bk_timeslot', 'bk_schedule.block', '=', 'bk_timeslot.id')
    ->join('bk_service', 'bk_schedule.id', '=','bk_service.bk_id')
    ->join('pr_service', 'pr_service.id', '=', 'bk_service.services')
    ->orderBy('date', 'ASC')            
    ->get();

  // var_dump($appointment); die;

    $today = date('Y-m-d');

    foreach($appointment as $appointments) {

        $date = strtotime($appointments->date);     

        $appointments->date = date('l: F d, Y',$date);              
    }


    $service = DB::table('bk_service')
        ->select('pr_service.service', 'pr_service.price')
        ->join('pr_service', 'pr_service.id', '=', 'bk_service.services')
        ->where('bk_service.userID', $id)
        ->where('bk_service.bk_id', $appointments->id)
        ->get();

   return View::make('appointments.history', array('pageTitle' => 'Apppointment History',
                                'today' => $today, 'service' => $service,
                                'appointment' => $appointment)); 
}
```

**Blade template:**

```
        <table class="main-table">
            <thead class="main-table-head">
                <th>Status/Result</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Block</th>
                <th>Services</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="main-table-head">
            @foreach($appointment as $appointments)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{{ $appointments->status }}}</td>
                    <td>{{{ $appointments->date }}}</td>
                    <td>{{{ $appointments->block }}}</td>
                    <td>
                        @foreach($service as $services)
                        {{{ $services->service }}}
                        @endforeach
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

This is essentially what I want it to look like. (it's an appointment history page if that helps)

```
userID  bk_id   services
44       117    1, 8, 22, 15
44       116    14
44       114    62
```

i tried to be detailed as possible it's been a pain trying to get this to work. I have attempted `GROUP_CONCAT`but I get the same problem (it's combing all the records for that userID)

**My attempt**

```
        $schedule = DB::table('bk_schedule')
            ->select( DB::raw('users_information.street_2, users_information.phone_2, users_information.apartment, bk_schedule.note, bk_schedule.date, bk_schedule.office, bk_status.status, bk_schedule.id, bk_schedule.userID, bk_timeslot.block, users_information.last_name, users_information.street_1, users_information.phone_1, users_information.user_zip_code, group_concat(pr_service.short_name SEPARATOR " | ") as group_service, group_concat(pr_service.service SEPARATOR ", ") as service_detail'))
            ->join('users_information', 'bk_schedule.userID', '=', 'users_information.id')
            ->join('bk_timeslot', 'bk_schedule.block', '=', 'bk_timeslot.id')
            ->join('bk_service', 'bk_schedule.userID', '=', 'bk_service.userID')
            ->join('pr_service', 'bk_service.services', '=', 'pr_service.id')
            ->join('bk_status', 'bk_schedule.status', '=', 'bk_status.id')
            ->orderBy('bk_schedule.date', 'asc')
            ->groupBy('bk_schedule.id')
            ->paginate(15);
```

**If anyone was curious as to my final solution.**

```
        $schedule = DB::table('bk_schedule')
            ->select( DB::raw('bk_schedule.office, pr_service.short_name, bk_timeslot.block, bk_schedule.date, bk_status.status, users_information.last_name, users_information.street_1, users_information.phone_1, users_information.user_zip_code, users_information.street_2, users_information.phone_2, users_information.apartment, bk_schedule.userID, bk_service.id, group_concat(pr_service.service)as service_detail, group_concat(pr_service.short_name)as group_service '))
            ->join('bk_service', 'bk_schedule.id', '=', 'bk_service.bk_id')
            ->join('users_information', 'bk_schedule.userID', '=', 'users_information.id')
            ->join('bk_status', 'bk_schedule.status', '=', 'bk_status.id')
            ->join('bk_timeslot', 'bk_schedule.block', '=', 'bk_timeslot.id')
            ->join('pr_service', 'bk_service.services', '=', 'pr_service.id')
            ->groupBy('bk_service.userID', 'bk_service.bk_id')
            ->paginate(15);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to group by both userId and booking id.

```
select sc.userId, sc.id, group_concat(services)
  from bk_schedule sc
  join bk_service se on (sc.id = se.bk_id)
 group by sc.userId, sc.id;
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61405/2)

Comment: FYI, you have a duplicate row in `bk_service` in your fiddle.